# How to save the token in the authifitication of the headers in Axios using Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, axios, http-headers, vuex

Here's the Login Action:

```
Login({ commit }, payload) {
      Axios.post('https://pure-reef-16205.herokuapp.com/api/login', payload)
        .then((response) => {
          // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
          console.log(response);
          commit('setToken', response.data.token);
        });
    },
```

Here's The Mutations :

```
 state.userToken = userToken;
      localStorage.setItem('Token', userToken);
      Axios.defaults.headers.common.Auth = userToken
    },
```

There is no bugs, just the auth is not saved in the headers
PS : i tried many methods and i think it's about 'u dont have access to modify the headers'...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@nuxtjs/axios` module with nuxt. It will be easier than configuring it yourself.
here is how you can do it with that module.

In your vuex action after you get token try `this.$axios.setToken(<idToken>, 'bearer')` and for common auth `this.$axios.setToken('<token>')`.

[Here](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/helpers.html#settoken) is documentation related to it

Comment: so i have to upload nuxtjs also.... more complicated

Answer (score 0):

You should never touch any tokens or cookies with javascript in your application.

If you can read/write any cookies/tokens with your javscript, then your application can be XSS attacked

Use `axios.withCredentials = true` for your auth